# Dynamic histogram in Shiny

Tags: r, web-applications, histogram, shiny

I'm creating a tool in R using Shiny. It's my first one and i'm having trouble getting my histogram to dynamically alter based on user defined inputs. I have a very simple table that i can get to behave in the desired fashion but I can't seem to do this with a plot. here is how i'm doing it with the table.

```
output$view <- renderTable({
  head(
subset(
  offerwallData, 
            platform == formulaTextPlatform() & 
            source == formulaTextSource() &
            type == formulaTextType() &
            price == formulaTextPrice() &
            country == formulaTextCountry()), 100)
  })
```

I want to do something like

```
output$plot <- RenderPlot({
    hist(subset...
})
```

but that doesn't want to work.

Comment: If you post all of `ui.R` and `server.R` this will be pretty straightforward to figure out.

Comment: It might be as simple as `renderPlot` starting with a lowercase R, not uppercase. This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to change dynamically based on user inputs, you need to make it a reactive object. Something like the following:

```
my.graph <- reactive({
  head(
    subset(
      offerwallData, 
      platform == formulaTextPlatform() & 
      source == formulaTextSource() &
      type == formulaTextType() &
      price == formulaTextPrice() &
      country == formulaTextCountry()), 100)
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  hist(my.graph())
})
```